# Babel Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: javascript, babeljs, storybook

I'm trying to run storybook on an expo installation. So I only got expo and storybook in the app so far.

I'm not able to start the storybook for web.

My package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "^32.0.0",
  "react": "16.5.0",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.1.6",
  "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^4.1.6",
  "@storybook/addon-links": "^4.1.6",
  "@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "^4.1.6",
  "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes": "^4.1.6",
  "@storybook/addons": "^4.1.6",
  "@storybook/react": "^4.1.6",
  "@storybook/react-native": "^4.1.6",
  "babel-loader": "^7",
  "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
  "react-dom": "16.5.0"
},
```

My babel.config.js looks like this;

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

I have also tried with:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  };
};
```

I get this error when trying to run the storybook:

```
ERROR in ./storybook/addons.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@storybook/react-native/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/babel-preset-react/lib/index.js
    at createDescriptor (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at items.map (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at passPerPreset (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:58:96)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at presets.presets (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:29:84)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
    at /Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
    at buildRootChain (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:68:29)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:85:55)
    at Object.loadPartialConfig (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@storybook/react-native/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:140:26)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/kristoffernielsen/repos/app/storybook/node_modules/@storybook/react-native/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:3:103)
 @ multi ./storybook/addons.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react-native/dist/manager/index.js manager[0]
```

It fails even though my addons.js is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't help you.
You still need your addon.js file.

Look here: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/5249

I think you need to wait it out.

https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/5249#issuecomment-472179512

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this renaming deleting or renaming the file to rn-addons.js

Comment: Can you be more clear regarding which file to delete and rename?

Answer (score -1):

Just to add `.babelrc` to your storybook folder with the default react native or expo presets.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YxAO.png) works for me:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```